# On which Stack Exchange community can I ask a question about Old Norse translation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, languages

I have an Old Norse phrase which I believe is not grammatically correct. Therefore I seek help of people who are familiar with the language at least (Which I am not) to find out if it is really incorrect and help me with the correct version of the sentence.

But I cannot figure out on which community can it be posted. As a matter of fact I am not even sure if such a community exists at all on our network.

I looked at [Culture and Creation category](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation) communities but all of the language sites there are dedicated either to some language or to technologies/techniques linked with linguistics.

The Closest ones are:

1. History Stack Exchange
2. English Stack Exchange (Because it has an Old-Norse tag but the tag has no description on when to use it therefore I am not sure. Also, it's English Stack Exchange so I doubt it will be on-topic there)

So that leaves me with History Stack Exchange. Can I post that question on History Stack Exchange? Or there is some other community more suited for this type of question which I might have overlooked?

Comment: If there is any place to ask at all, it is [Linguistics.se], as they handle any language-specific questions not covered by a site dedicated to that language (and of course we do not have a sister dedicated to Old Norse), but I'm not sure they do translations. OTOH you've already done your own translation, and just want to know if it's grammatical, and having done your homework first usually works in your favor.

Comment: If it happens to come from an ancient Norse myth, then _maybe_ it's on-topic on [Mythology.SE]. You could ask if it's on-topic on their Meta or in their chat, before posting.

Comment: @DanBron I thought that SE was for study of linguistics as a subject. Are you certain asking for the correct translation would be on topic there? Or should I post on their meta first?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks for the suggestion. It is however not from the Mythology. I was just listening to a viking metal song and I wanted to translate it to old norse so I just looked up a few articles and dictionaries and created one for myself which is most likely wrong.

Comment: @NSNoob A Viking metal song... maybe one of the music sites? Although I have a hunch that translations of lyrics are ruled off-topic there. (And their expertise probably isn't in ancient Norse.. although you never know  :-) )

Comment: @S.L.Barth I won't be asking for lyrics translations of course. Just one phrase. Rísa í inn hrið Vikingr Guðin which is according to me "Rise in the storms, Viking gods". It is of course, assuming that grammar would be somewhat similar in English and Norse seeing as both are Germanic languages but that can be wrong given that grammar is different between Germanic family

Comment: @NSNoob I did say "I'm not sure they do translations". The only thing I wanted to get across is if *any* stack can address this question, it's Linguistics.

Comment: FWIW If I translate that English sentence to my native language, Dutch, I do get something that looks similar to the Norse sentence. You could also look for help in the Tavern on the Meta, we have a few people interested in linguistics there.